# Why my package is not correctly exported in node_modules after build in pnpm monorepo

Tags: monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

First of all, let me apologize if I make so many mistakes in this posts, since I don't really understand how dependencies work and how monorepos are handled (I am trying :P ).

I am currently using a huge monorepo with 12 packages and 2 apps. It is working with no problems with yarn, but I am considering migrating to pnpm specially because of performance issues and to decrease how long it takes to install.

My current problem is that pnpm is way more strict, so I am getting an error regarding to another subpackage not exporting something.

```
src/components/StatusBall.tsx:6:3 - error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/services/lib/status"' has no exported member 'serverID'.

6   serverID,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is not exactly correct, if I go to the "services" package lib (dist) folder, it is properly compiled, but If i go to StatusBall and I use ctrl+click it sends me to

```
...frontend\node_modules\.pnpm\@focus+services@1.15.1_sfoxds7t5ydpegc3knd667wn6m\node_modules\services\lib\status\index.d.ts
```

But this file is missing the export serverId I can see in my lib folder.

What is wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to pnpm [v7.29.0](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/releases/tag/v7.29.0). Then add these settings to the `.npmrc` in the root of your project or workspace:

```
dedupe-peer-dependents=true
auto-install-peers=true
```

NOTE: These settings are true by default already in pnpm v8.0.0-beta.0

Then remove `pnpm-lock.yaml`, `node_modules`, and run `pnpm install`.